# My Web Form inserts only the first item in dropdown no matter what I choose

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I have two relational tables: the Profiles table which contains 3 kinds of user roles (Manager, Developer, Common User) and the Users table which contains information about the user and their roles ID (Profile_ID field) in the Access 2010 database.

I created a Webform in ASP.NET which should simply register users, asking for their names, selecting their roles in a dropdown list and inserting it all in the Access database. The code populates a **grid view** with every registred user and a **dropdown list** with each role on page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Start connection
    Dim cs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Access 2010").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
    cn.Open()

    'Retrieve User Data
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With
    Dim ddlValues As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    'Populate User Grid View
    grdUsers.DataSource = ddlValues
    grdUsers.DataBind()
    ddlValues.Close()

    'Retrieve Profile data
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Profiles"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()


    'Populate Dropdown Profiles
    ddRoles.DataSource = ddlValues
    ddRoles.DataTextField = "Nome"
    ddRoles.DataValueField = "ID"
    ddRoles.DataBind()

    'Close connections
    ddlValues.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    cn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Lately it inserts into the database once button clicked:

```
Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    Dim cs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Access 2010").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (nome, Profile_ID) VALUES ('" & Me.txtNome.Text & "', " & Me.ddRoles.SelectedValue & ")"
        .Connection = cn
        .Connection.Open()
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Connection.Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
    cn.Dispose()
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub
```

The code runs without problems but no matter which item in the dropdown I choose it will always create as Common User (which is the first record in this table). Although I checked the html generated:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddRoles" id="MainContent_ddRoles">
<option value="5">Common User</option>
<option value="6">Developer</option>
<option value="7">Manager</option>
```

It seems right, but my database only has records with the ID number 5. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blowing away the selection in the DropDown list by binding on every call to Page_Load.  You need to only bind when !IsPostback.

Comment: In Page_Load call that Sub If Not IsPostBack Then BindDropDowns End If